# xhr to service with windows authentication

Tags: xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication

To access in browser web service using windows authentication I add the following:xhr.withCredentials= true;

Is it enough? Sometimes browser still shows windows asking for user win  credentials. More details.

https://localhost:44386/api uses windows auth. Some users are allowed, some not - for test. Here is js code. Is it ok? Sometimes users still get dialog asking for teir windows credentials.

```
function send() {
            const url = 'https://localhost:44386/api/values';

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.open("GET", url);
            xhr.onload = () => requestComplete(xhr);
            xhr.send();
        };
```

Comment: Hey, I think your question could use a bit more context and maybe code samples? What are you trying to achieve? What are you using? What is the surrounding code?

Comment: @tomr  added some details